# How to use a column as part of mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, join, split

Only in a sql query (used in a php script), I need to use the value of a column into the query to optimize the speed but it doesn't work well.
I have mutiple tables so I use JOIN

If I do that :

```
LEFT JOIN `gestdetails` gd ON gd.id IN (205467,205468,205469)
```

I works well !
But if I use the value of a column (gc.details = 205467,205468,205469) :

```
LEFT JOIN `gestdetails` gd ON gd.id IN (gc.details)
```

It doesn't work, it only use the first value '205467'.

I'm trying to do that to go faster with the query : if I do the classic JOIN on id = id, it also works but it's way too long...

```
LEFT JOIN `gestdetails` gd ON (gd.idcommande = gc.id)
```

gestcommandes = table of unique orders
gestdetails = table of multiple products linked to idcommande of gestcommandes

Here is the full query :

```
SELECT
            gc.*,
            count(gd.idcommande),
            GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(gd.id,"@",gd.idcommande,"@",gd.ref,"@",gd.poids,"@",gd.numcolis,"@",gd.designation,"@",gd.prix) SEPARATOR "|"),
            ad.*
        FROM
        `gestcommandes` gc 
        LEFT JOIN `gestdetails` gd ON gd.id IN (gc.details)
        LEFT JOIN `adresses` ad ON ad.id_commande = gc.id
        WHERE 
        `mp` LIKE '%-eb' AND (`statut` = 5 OR `statut` = 6) AND `date_expe` >= '2020-04-07 00:00:00' AND `date_expe` <= '2020-04-07 23:59:59'
        AND
        ad.is_delivery = 1
        GROUP BY
        gc.id
```

Executing this query, it only uses the first number into the gc.details column (i.e '205467' from '205467,205468,205469' and of course, I've got warnings :
*Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: '205467,205468,205469'*

gc.details can count 1 to 100 numbers...

I tryed so many things, I don't manage to do it, so if anybody can help me (without creating procedure)... thank you !

ps : the "GROUP_CONCAT" part works well... if I manage to get more than 1 result for the details...

Comment: use `FIND_IN_SET`  instead of `IN`

Comment: Thank you ! when I use FIND_IN_SET it's working ! but it's longer... way tooo long to execute... that's so strange

Comment: Since the query is very very fast with the values directly written into the query, I wonder if the solution is not about converting the "gc.details" column, to transform it like if it was directly numbers written... Am I clear ? :)